# Normalise an array

Tags: arrays, r

I am trying to normalise an array within a specified dimension of it
(by normalise I mean to divide each element by the sum over the relevant dimension).

I would like to somehow automate the calculation, where the dimension to normalise the array over, is given, 
and the same function is used to generate the output, for each. While I can generate the required sums, I cannot
normalise them with a consistent technique.

An mwe

```
a = array(1:8, c(2,2,2))

dm = 1 # dimension to sum over
ndim = length(dim(a))
margin = setdiff(seq_len(ndim), dm) # dimensions to keep in apply
a / rep(apply(a, margin, sum), each=2)

, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.4285714
[2,] 0.6666667 0.5714286

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.4545455 0.4666667
[2,] 0.5454545 0.5333333


dm = 3 # dimension to sum over
ndim = length(dim(a))
margin = setdiff(seq_len(ndim), dm) 
a / rep(apply(a, margin, sum), times=2)
# but for this dimension `times`, instead of `each` was used

, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.1666667 0.3000000
[2,] 0.2500000 0.3333333

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.8333333 0.7000000
[2,] 0.7500000 0.6666667


#for dim=2 the denominator is more difficult to generate
dm = 2 # dimension to sum over
a / c(4,6,4,6,12,14,12,14)
```

While it would be preferable not to use loops (apply etc included), any solution is welcome. Thanks

---

As requested in the comments, an example on a matrix (if it was only 2x2 arrays this would be more straight forward)

```
a = array(1:4, c(2,2))
a
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
dm = 1 # dimension to sum over
ndim = length(dim(a))
margin = setdiff(seq_len(ndim), dm) # dimensions to keep in apply
apply(a, margin, sum)
# [1] 3 7
a / rep(apply(a, margin, sum), each=2)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.3333333 0.4285714
#[2,] 0.6666667 0.5714286

dm = 2 # dimension to sum over
ndim = length(dim(a))
margin = setdiff(seq_len(ndim), dm) # dimensions to keep in apply
apply(a, margin, sum)
# [1] 4 6
a / rep(apply(a, margin, sum), times=2)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.2500000 0.7500000
#[2,] 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a 2x2 matrix, a given dimension, the sum that would be calculated with that matrix and dimension, and the corresponding normalized matrix?

Comment: @cameronroytaylor; I have updated, ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consistency that you seek can be obtained by using [sweep](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/advanced_function_r.htm#sweep):

```
normalize <- function(a,dm){
  ndim <- length(dim(a))
  margin <- setdiff(seq_len(ndim),dm)
  sweep(a,margin,apply(a, margin, sum),"/")
}
```

Then `normalize(a,1)`, `normalize(a,2)`, and `normalize(a,3)` simplify to the arrays that you want.